# Running execute statement within SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I have a statement that runs a stored procedure:

```
SELECT TOP(10) 
    'exec dbo.PurgeResults '''+ Description + ''',''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd,-30,GetDate()), 101)  + '''' 
FROM
    Alerts
```

The result I get is like this but there's a lot.

```
exec dbo.PurgeResults '127 - PM_Sanitation','09/03/2018'
```

How do I turn that statement I have to run the exec inside the result? I'm not sure if I am phasing it correctly.

Comment: Right now you are only displaying the `exec` command as a string which is an output from select query

Comment: It's displaying a string but how can i output and run it. I'm trying to eliminate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your results into a temp table, and then loop through them and execute them as you would dynamic sql. You can modify your existing query like this:

```
DECLARE @QueryStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT TOP(10) 
Query = 'exec dbo.PurgeResults '''+ Description + ''',''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd,-30,GetDate()), 101)  + '''' 
INTO #QueryTable
FROM Alerts

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #QueryTable)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 
        @QueryStatement = Query 
    FROM #QueryTable

    EXEC(@QueryStatement)

    DELETE #QueryTable
    WHERE Query = @QueryStatement
END
```

Comment: Yes. You can verify it yourself. Create a simple stored proc, then try to call it with `DECLARE @QueryStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC procName'; EXEC(@QueryStatement)`

Comment: No way to test it right now, appreciate the answer though :-)

Comment: Testing this right now, i'll let you know in a few.

Comment: It works, I had to add a `drop table` command to be able to rerun it.